# Help with Hop Analysis

Tags: beer, hops, alpha-acids, growing-hops, ibu

I'll try this again. If you grow your own hops, would you pay to have them analyzed? If you have had your hops analyzed, did the analysis help you in subsequent brewing? Was it worth the cost (e.g. how expensive was it, what is a reasonable cost per sample, and would you do it again)?

BTW -  thanks for the editing suggestion, theraccoonbrew :-) I'm not marketing, have honest questions about whether there is a decent level of interest in this and what those who have had it done have experienced. Not certain where a better forum to ask this is, but would certainly appreciate suggestions where to ask if you don't think it belongs here at Homebrewing.

Comment: Wanted to add as an aside, this is a great idea, just not sure it's practical. With reasonably accurate numbers, home brewers could use home grown hops to much greater effect.  Right now we just guess based on the min and max alpha of the variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between myself and my co-brewer Scott and his father we have a total of nine plants, of mostly different varieties.  We get a nice crop of hops out of it.  But to be honest, not enough to bother having them analyzed.

In a dried state, we get a few of ounces of dried hop flowers per plant, enough for a few beers each.  Coupled with the fact we are growing a couple of varieties that makes it tough.  We would have to devote a LOT more time, effort and space to growing more of the same hops before it became worthwhile.  With the small quantities, it's hard to sacrifice any of it for analysis.

I wasn't aware of any practical way for a home-grower to even realistically have them analyzed.  I hate to say it, but given the cost of hops and the small quantity most home brewers grow, the cost would have to be less than $10.00 to even consider it.

That being said, it WOULD be nice to know if our cultivars are growing within the expected range for the variety.

Comment: I do appreciate the response. Best brewing. :-)

Comment: TinCoyote, how old are your hop plants?  I have one 10 year old Cascade and last year I got 6-7 lb. after drying.

Comment: @Denny-I'm guessing it's because TinCoyote lives in the "Upper midwest".  I imagine the harsh climate has some affect on hop production.  Here in central Virginia, I know a guy who's 3 plants produces more than he could ever use.  I'm sure it also depends on the variety, not all varieties grow well outside of the hop growing regions of Oregon, Washington, and Idaho.

Comment: This will be the third year. It may be due to the age of the plants, as suggested or just the climate here in Wisconsin.  Interesting points, though.

Comment: BTW, at my house at least, I am growing East Kent Goldings, Liberty, and Nugget.

Comment: I'm in the old west-side hop area of WA and we still find naturalized hops along trails in august, I'm curious about the Alpha levels though I suppose they are all misc seedling crosses by now. All hop farms moved to the east-side about 70 years ago after the dams provided irrigation water, too much chance for disease on the humid west-side. (I tossed some in a bag of peaches during a walk last summer and after a day the two flavors blended very nice.)